# AVStream.duration has a wrong value

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get to the end of my video stream.

But AVStream.duration gives a wrong value, and I have to use `av_rescale_q` to convert `AV_TIME_BASE` timestamp from FormatContext.duration to stream time_base timestamp.

```
print("{}\n", formatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->duration);
current_frame_timestamp = av_rescale_q(formatCtx->duration, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, formatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->time_base);
print("{}\n", current_frame_timestamp);

-9223372036854775808
3653000
```

Answer (score 1):

-9223372036854775808 is probably AV_NOPTS_VALUE which means no pts/dts present (or invalid).